# Selected page append css class to the selected link

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Inside my asp.net mvc4 app I have menus which is stored inside Shared folder as partial view
like

```
<li class="menu-title">
        <a class="title" href="#">Main menu</a>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu_items" style="display: list-item;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "My Index")
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("About", "Index", "About")
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
```

How can I send from controller some flag to the view where I would append css class to selected link, for example if visitor click first link (Index) when this page loads I want this menu partial to be

```
<li class="submenu_items" style="display: list-item;">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "My Index", new {@class="selected "})
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("About", "Index", "About")
                </li>    
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight a selected menu, We can make use of custom Html helper, Scott has written an wonderful article on this check this link

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/25/asp-net-mvc-highlight-current-link.aspx